# How can I add a repo with a .repo file with ansible?

Tags: centos, yum, ansible

[According to the docs on `rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), I'm supposed to run

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/repo/epel-7/carlwgeorge-ripgrep-epel-7.repo
$ sudo yum install ripgrep
```

How do I get that first `yum-config-manager` into ansible?

Comment: Evan, the two answers (yours that you chose to leave unaccepted, and SteveGoob with the get_url module) provide different tactics towards the same end. Consider this:HOW do you want to accomplish the task. Do you want to pull the repo file from the maintainers "source of truth" they have published? If 'Yes' then using get_url is probably the better path. Your answer using 'yum_resository' is perfectly acceptable but requires you maintain the details of the repo. `get_url` maintains idempotence if the maintainer CHANGES the repo details... Yours would require you change the playbook manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better yet, try using something like this:

```
- name: Ripgrep Repo
  get_url:
    url: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/repo/epel-7/carlwgeorge-ripgrep-epel-7.repo
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/copr_ripgrep.repo
```

This is probably the most "Ansible" way to solve the problem if you don't care to install `yum-config-manager`.

---

### Old Answer

You shouldn't actually need `yum-config-manager` to complete this task. All that command does in this context is put that remote file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. After that, `yum` will be able to pull packages from that repository. Something like,

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/copr_ripgrep.repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/repo/epel-7/carlwgeorge-ripgrep-epel-7.repo
```

...should do the trick. `curl` would work as well if `wget` isn't available.

Alternatively, you could install `yum-config-manager` first and then use it as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can add the .repo by url, so what I did was to open it up and convert it into the directives necessary for `yum-repository`.

```
name: Add repository for ripgrep for epel7
       yum_repository:
         name: cgor
         description: EPEL YUM repo
         baseurl: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/repo/epel-7/carlwgeorge-ripgrep-epel-7.repo
         name: copr
         description: Copr repo for ripgrep owned by carlwgeorge
         baseurl: https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/epel-7-$basearch/
         gpgkey: https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/carlwgeorge/ripgrep/pubkey.gpg
         gpgcheck: yes
         repo_gpgcheck: no
         enabled: yes
         skip_if_unavailable: true
```

I'll leave this un-accepted, because I don't think this is ideal.